# VBA - Accessing and looking up values in CSV files efficiently

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am working on a complex model that needs to lookup values in a series of distinct tables.  If I embed all of the information in the model itself, then the file quickly becomes unwieldy.  I am hoping to find a solution where I can have a series of CSV files that contain all of the lookup tables, and then have my VBA code just quickly read each CSV file as necessary and return the appropriate value.
My initial thought is to read each CSV file in working memory as needed, lookup the necessary values, then discard the information once the lookups are complete. Is that most efficient way to do it?

Comment: Could you load all your lookups into memory for the whole session, or would they be too large?  What kind of lookups are you doing - just two-column or can the lookup value be from one of a number of columns?

Comment: The lookups can be from multiple columns, but primarily just two-column stuff (or, more specifically, looking up the different 2-column combos in the same table multiple times - matching columns A and C, then B and D, then A and E, etc.)...I am not sure what memory limits are, but the tables are anywhere from a few hundred rows to 30,000 or 40,000 rows...

Comment: During a previous mission, I had excellent efficiency and reusability by creating a class module for each of the lookup file "types" I had to use. The advantage of this is that if the layout ever changes, you only have to update your class module. Additionally, if you work in a team, you can easily export and share those class modules.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea which might work for you: load your csv file into a variant array the first time it's required, then subsequent calls will use the cached data.  You can lookup values in any column and return the corresponding value from any other column.

**EDIT**: updated to show how to populate lookup arrays from CSV files

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim arr1, arr2

    arr1 = CsvToArray("D:\Analysis\tmp\Data1.csv")
    arr2 = CsvToArray("D:\Analysis\tmp\Data2.csv")

    Debug.Print TestLookup(arr1, "lookup1", 2, 1)
    Debug.Print TestLookup(arr2, "lookup2", 3, 1)
    'bunch more lookups...
End Sub


Function TestLookup(arr, val, lookincol As Integer, returnfromcol As Integer)
    Dim r
    r = Application.Match(val, Application.Index(arr, 0, lookincol), 0)
    If Not IsError(r) Then
        TestLookup = arr(r, returnfromcol)
    Else
        TestLookup = "Not found" 'or some other "error" value
    End If
End Function


Function CsvToArray(filepath As String) As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filepath)
    CsvToArray = wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    wb.Close False
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - I like this method, but I am not sure I understand it completely...I see how this is function is doing the look-up with a dynamic 'lookin' and 'returnfrom' col, but I am not clear on how I read the data from a file into an array (forgive my ignorance).  I was thinking I would read each CSV into a user-defined type variable (I know file structures in advance) with a distinct variable array for each column.  I would then pass my type variable to the lookup function to return the appropriate match.  Is that compatible with this solution?  Thanks again!

Comment: See edits: I altered the lookup function to add the data array as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply - I got this code working properly with my model.  My last question would be related to efficiency/performance - is loading the CSV file into an actual workbook going to be a fast way to do it?  My initial inclination was to read the file directly into an array through file scripting code - could you comment briefly on how efficient this method is versus reading the whole file into a giant string, for example, and then parsing the string based on the commas and new lines?

Comment: That's easy to test: if you're concerned about performance then you can easily run the relevant code in a loop and compare timings. I suspect opening the cvs as a workbook might be slightly slower, but maybe not if you factor in the time it takes to create the other approach.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

if you really have to do it in excel, then this is a method:

```
Function GetData(This As String, ResultCol As Integer)
Dim LastRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Turn off screen refreshing

Workbooks.Open Filename:="E:\my_files\tables.csv" 'Open the CSV file

LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row 'used for range in vlookup
GetData = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(This, Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, ResultCol)), ResultCol, False)

Workbooks("Tables.csv").Close 'Close the CSV file

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Turn on screen refreshing

End Function
```